# Get request disappears in php after post call

Tags: php, javascript, post, get

I have been stuck with this bug for a long time now, and i  simply have to little knowledge of php to solve it. So i pray for your help.

My problem is, that after i make a post (or ajax) request to my site, the GET request disappears and thus leaving me a NULL object (since i create my object from that id).

I have made some tests, and the problem is at the GET is NULL in the response i got from the POST. And this doesn't happen if i forget about the get and just initiates the id as a random number.

Here are some parts of my code where i think the problem is:

First is the php with my GET:

```
require 'php/functions.php';

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];  

    // $id = 5;

    try {
    $bar = getBarById($id);
    } catch (exception $e) {
        exit;
    }
```

After this i output some date from the object and it works all fine, the GET is being initiated here.

Now. When i make my ajax (i tried regular POST also) request, the status response from POST is OK, but after that nothing happens and det response says that my GET request is NULL.

The JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function save(value) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "barpage.php",
data: { save_sum: value }
}).done(function(msg) {
    msg.preventDefault();
 alert( msg );
});
}
```

Just for the record. It is the "msg" response from ajax that tells me that nothing happens. and that "$id" is NULL.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your not setting a get parameter... `barpage.php?id=5` would be what you need for `url:`.

Comment: personally I would recommend answer by deleteman.. and I think you were just trying out get you do not need it. I would recommend just use post and $_POST.. use ternary operator to make your code readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the deal:

Your AJAX request is doing a POST request, thus the GET array is not being filled, because, well, you're doing a POST request instead of a GET one. A quick fix would be to send the Id as part of the ajax request and on your php file, ask for it like this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
if($id == null) { 
   $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
}
```

**An alternative solution**

```
$id = null;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
   $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
}
```

**An even better solution** (from comment bellow)

```
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : null;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: He can search direclty for `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: @PlamenNikolov Thanks for the suggestion, I've added your idea to the list of possible solutions :)

Comment: Okay so i should send 'id' along with 'save_sum' in ajax?

Comment: @user1627114 yes, just do something like: 'data: { save_sum: value, id: <?=$id?> }'

Answer (score 0):

You are `POST`-ing your data to your PHP page, rather than sending a `GET` request.

```
function save(value) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "barpage.php",
data: { save_sum: value }
}).done(function(msg) {
    msg.preventDefault();
    alert( msg );
});
}
```

Or you could do a `POST` but put the `GET` variables in your `url` object:

```
function save(value) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "barpage.php?id=5",
data: { save_sum: value }
}).done(function(msg) {
    msg.preventDefault();
    alert( msg );
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong several things:

- making POST ajax request but in the same time searching for a GET parameters
- POST the data `save_sum` but look for `id`

Anyway here are possible solutions but we cannot guess what you do exactly:

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "barpage.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
    data: { save_sum: value }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        msg.preventDefault();
     alert( msg );
    });
  }
```

or change the type to "GET":

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "barpage.php?",
    data: { save_sum: value, id: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        msg.preventDefault();
     alert( msg );
  });
}
```